# Convert an input file to ascii python

Tags: python, ascii

I'm trying to write a program that opens a file, reads the file and then converts the file into ASCII characters and then writes those characters into and output file. However, when I run the program I get <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Output.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

```
def convert_to_ascii(file,Output):
 F = open(file, 'r')
 B = open(Output, 'w')
 F_line=str(F.readline())
 for _ in F:
     B.write([ord(str(F_line[i])) for i in F_line])
 F.close()
 B.close()

file = input('what file do you wish to convert?')

convert_to_ascii(file,'Output.txt')

p=open('Output.txt', 'r')
print(p)
```

Comment: Of course you get that output, what else do you expect to happen when you `print` the file object? You probably want to call `.read()` on it to get the contents. Also, the "convert to ascii" part in your title makes no sense, you seem to convert the data to the _ordinal values_ of the respective ASCII characters. Oh, and please rewrite your `for` loop as it is utter nonsense and certainly does not do what you want (hint: actually use your loop variable). I'd suggest you go read a few tutorials and play around in the python interpreter for a while to learn the basics of the language.

Comment: Please show a sample input and the expected output. It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
file_content = open(file, 'r').read()
file_content = ''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in file_content))
open('Output.txt','w').write(file_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would print the output file. Try something like this:

```
input_file = input("Enter the file name to read from: ")
output_file = input("Enter the file name to write to: ")
file_write = open(output_file, "w")

inputFile = open(input_file)
buffer = ""
for line in inputFile:
    for i in line:
        if i.isalpha():
            buffer += bin(ord(i))[2:]
file_write.write(buffer)

file_write.close()
inputFile.close()
```

the [2:] removes the '0b' that is being converted into the output file.